# How to select all sub nodes by classname under a specific node I choosed In puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

What is the best practice for selecting all `section-item` elements in `section-one` from the following HTML structure:

```html
<div>
 <div id="section-one">
  <div class="data-list">
   <div class="section-item">1-1</div>
   <div class="section-item">1-2</div>
   <div class="section-item">1-3</div>
   <div class="section-item">1-4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-item">1-5</div>
 </div>
 <div id="section-two">
  <div class="section-item">2-1</div>
  <div class="section-item">2-2</div>
  <div class="section-item">2-3</div>
  <div class="section-item">2-4</div>
  <div class="section-item">2-5</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

One way to achieve this is by selecting `section-one` and then finding all its child nodes with class `section-item`. Are there any more efficient ways to accomplish this? (Also, I want to ignore how 'deep' the node is, once the classname matched, get all of them)

Comment: I'm not sure about puppeteer, but what about `document.querySelectorAll("#section-one .section-item")`?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Do you have a performance problem with your current approach, whatever it is? I don't think you need to micro-optimize selecting this.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to select it via

```js
const items = await page.$$('#section-one .section-item');
```